# Как убрать все вхождения сочетания символов из строки SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как убрать все вхождения %_AA% из строки в MSSQL?

Что есть:

```
1 NBC1,NBC2,NAA1,NAA6  
2 NAA2  
3 NMA1,NAA4,NAA2,ABC1
```

Что должно быть:

```
1 NBC1,NBC2  
2   
3 NMA1,ABC1
```

Написала запрос

```
CASE
WHEN qwe LIKE ‘%_AA%’ THEN
REPLACE(qwe,SUBSTRING(qwe,PATINDEX(‘%ZZ%’,qwe)-1,5),’’) 
ELSE qwe 
END
```

но он убирает только первое вхождение, второе-третье остаётся. Как сделать лучше?

Comment: Какая версия SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE test
SET csv = ( SELECT STRING_AGG(value, ',')
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(test.csv, ',')
            WHERE value NOT LIKE '_AA_' );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b38ab7dad6c13b378b280a94418c011d)

Comment: Классное решение. Единственно, что порядок сборки не гарантируется.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko 1) Для перетасовки исходного относительного положения элементов - на самом деле надо постараться. 2) STRING_SPLIT имеет возможность WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY. Если позиционность имеет значение - следует использовать позиционный формат, включающий компоненту номера записи в наборе, а не строковый тип.

Comment: Я это знаю. :-)